# Why $\int _0 ^t \phi_s ^2 ds < \infty \ \mathbb P \text{-a.e.}$ do not implies $\mathbb E [\int _0 ^t \phi_s ^2 ds] < \infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Why $\phi =(\phi_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ is a progressive mesurable stochastic process 
 do not implies $\mathbb E [\int _0 ^t \phi_s ^2 ds] < \infty$?

I know that if $X$ is a positive random variable such that $\mathbb E [X]< \infty$ then $X < \infty \ \mathbb P \text{-a.e.}$. However I don't remember how to prove it and neither why it's not equivalent (in other words, why does not the implication work in the inverse sense).

Could someone help me with this little doubt please ?

Comment: Well all you need to "prove" they're not equivalent is a counterexample. A Cauchy distributed RV will give you that.

Comment: Or maybe simpler to see anything that has a tail that looks like a power law with the exponent greater than 1 but less than 2

Answer (score 2):

The converse is not true. The [Cauchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) random variable is finite a.s. but it does not have defined its mean. Same with the [Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) distribution for $\alpha \leq 1$ where the mean is infinite.

The property you mention comes from measure theory. If a function $f > 0$ is not finite a.e. then the integral of $f$ is already infinite over $\{f=\infty\}$. For general $f$ if also you have a non negligible set where is $-\infty$ then the integral is not defined.

Comment: Dear @Bunder, I am a freshman of stochastic process and I also have interesting in this problem. I am a little confused that in your counterexample, do you mean the density of $\phi(t)$ at time $t$ is  $1/(\pi(1+(tx)^2))$ or others?

Comment: @Lion I'm talking about a random variable, not a process. The density you mention is similar to the one of a Cauchy Process (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_process) which has a relation with the Cauchy random variable.

Comment: Do you mean that $\int_0^t\phi_s^2 ds$ is the R.V. you mentioned? Say, for example, it can be Cauchy R.V. for a counterexample?

Comment: No, what I mean is that in general the assertion in the title is not true. I could be that the RV $\int_0^t \ldots$ is finite a.s. without having a finite expectation. 

The integral in this case cannot be a Cauchy RV since the former is positive a.s. whereas the support of a Cauchy RV is $\mathbb{R}$